# Result of a Query.eq in mondodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I need to know the value of the return of `Query.Eq("Name", Textbox1.Text)` to see if the name from the `Textbox1.Text` really exists in the DB, if not I must show a message box to the user. I already tried comparing `Query.EQ` to `true` but the types are not the same.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: You'll need to provide more details about what isn't working. I'd expect the code to look like `Query.Eq("Name", Textbox1.Text)` if you're using C# and a control to get the text from. The control and property can't be quoted.

Comment: yes you are right, the textbox1.text doesnt have quotes. i am trying to do if query.eq("Name",Textbox1.text) = False to check if query.eq return false

Comment: No documents are returned if you use that query and no documents match.

Comment: and how can i check that?

Comment: It's documented here: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#find-and-findas-methods

Comment: yes i understood that but i dont know how to check it results are no documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to verify that there were no results, one way using `Query` would be:

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
var server = client.GetServer();

var database = server.GetDatabase("test"); // "test" is the name of the database
var collection = database.GetCollection("myCollection");

var results = collection.Find(Query.EQ("Name", Textbox1.Text));
if (results.Count() == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("no matches");
    // or MessageBox.Show(...)
}
```

The `results` object returned is a `MongoCursor`, which implements `IEnumerable`.

The static method `EQ` on `Query` is just just used to build a `QueryBuilder` instance which can be passed to any one of the various methods on a `MongoCollection` that accept an object that implements `IMongoQuery` as a parameter.

If you don't need to gather the specific matches, you could also just use `Count`:

```
var totalMatches = collection.Count(Query.EQ("Name", Textbox1.Text));
```

Comment: collection has no find attribute

Comment: Added full example to show where `collection` was retrieved.

Comment: thanks very much it worked. but there is no other way without having to quert the db twice?

Comment: Why would you be querying the database twice? The example above doesn't. A call to `Find` does the actual query to the database.

Comment: yes but then i need a variables with the result from the query. i was using findone to get only one result

Comment: If you use `Find`, it returns an enumerable list of `BsonDocument`, which can then be used to get the document fields.